# Resizing a partition in TinyCore without losing data

Tags: command-line, tinycore

I have the following doubt about TinyCore: how to can I resize the boot partition (the only partition available) without losing data?

I believe I have to:

- boot to command prompt using some live system
- check what partition I want to resize (`fdisk -l`)
- unmount the partition, then run: `resize2fs -p /dev/sdxy new_sizeM` (eg `/dev/sdc1 7600M`).

Unmounting is done with `umount` and checking partition with `fdisk -l`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice the usage of [sytemrescuecd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) which includes tools like [gparted](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/).

Also make sure to backup your data beforehand, especially if you want to shrink your partition.

And you might want to consider to switch to LVM to be able to resize your partition live (without reboot) in the future.

Comment: thanks. was able to fix the problem with a slickly different approach

Comment: @tmm88 What approach?